# Prove that $a^5 ≡ a$ (mod 15) for every integer $a$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that $a^5 ≡ a$ (mod 15) for every integer $a$

- We are currently studying modular arithmetic and congruence and I came across this proof on my study set that I'm really not sure how to approach. We have gone over equivalence relations in mod arithmetic, equivalence classes (complete set of residues), and have gone through several mod arithmetic examples w/o variables. Looking through my notes and book I'm still not sure how to proceed with this problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is sufficient to proof this for a=0,...,14

Comment: Fermat's little theorem states $a^5 \equiv a \pmod 5$ maybe that helps somehow

Comment: $a^5 \equiv a\cdot a^4 \equiv a \pmod 5;$
$a^5 \equiv a^4 \cdot a \equiv (1)^2\cdot a \equiv a \pmod 3$.
Chinese remender theorem.

Comment: By [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) $a^5\equiv a\pmod{5}$. Also $a^5-a=(a-1)a(a+1)\cdot \left(a^2+1\right)$ is divisible by $3$, because exactly one of $a-1,a,a+1$ is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $a\in{\mathbb Z}$ then
$$c:==a^5-a=a(a-1)(a+1)(a^2+1)$$
is obviously divisible by $3$, and is obviously divisible by $5$ if $a\in\{-1,0,1\}\ {\rm mod}\ 5$. If $a=\pm2\ {\rm mod}\ 5$ then $a^2+1=0\ {\rm mod}\ 5$. It follows that $c=0\ {\rm mod}\ 15$ for all $a\in{\mathbb Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that an integer $n$ satisfies $n \equiv 0 \pmod{15}$ if and only if $n \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ and $n \equiv 0 \pmod 5$. Therefore, it suffices to prove that 
$a^5 \equiv a \pmod 5$ and $a^5 \equiv a \pmod 3$. The first formula follows from  [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).
For the second formula, it con for instance consider separately the three cases:

1. if $a \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, then $a^5 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$,
2. if $a \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, then $a^5 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$
3. if $a \equiv -1 \pmod 3$, then $a^5 \equiv -1 \pmod 3$.

Comment: By Fermat's little theorem (all congruences are modulo $3$), $a^3\equiv a$, so $a^5\equiv a^3\equiv a$. No need to do cases.

Answer (score 1):

Fermat little theorem:

$a^5 \equiv a \mod 5$ so $a^5 -a \equiv 0 \mod 5$.

If $3\not |a$, $a^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ so $a^5 \equiv a \mod 3$ so $a^5 -a \equiv 0 \mod 3$

So, $a^5 -a \equiv 0 \mod 15$.

Or... we could factor $a^5 - a = (a-1)a (a+1)(a^2+1) $.  $3|(a-1)a (a+1)$ and $5|a^2 +1 \iff 5|a^2+5a+6=(a+2)(a+3) $ and $5|(a-1)a (a+1)(a+2)(a+3) $

Comment: $a^4\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ is true if and only if $5\nmid a$. Whereas $a^5\equiv a\pmod{5}$ is true for all $a\in\mathbb Z$. Both can be called Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem is $a^p\equiv a\pmod{p}$.

Comment: Gosh I was tired and don't like typing on my phone...